# how to use output of one proccess into another in nextflow?

Tags: nextflow

I have created a process create_parallel_params whose output is parallel_params folder containing {0..9}.json. These will already created by parallel_paramgen.py.

```
process create_parallel_params{
    publishDir "./nf_output", mode: 'copy'
    input:
    val x
    output:
    path parallel_params
    
    script:
    """
    mkdir parallel_params | python $TOOL_FOLDERS/parallel_paramgen.py \
    parallel_params \
    $x
    """
}
```

I want to pass this create_parallel_params output into another process(searchlibrarysearch_molecularv2_parallelstep1) to take these json file in parallel  and process it.

```
process searchlibrarysearch_molecularv2_parallelstep1{
    publishDir "./nf_output", mode: 'copy'
    input:
    path parallel_params
    path params.spectra
    path params.library
    output:
    file 'intermediateresults'

    script:
    """
    mkdir intermediateresults convert_binary librarysearch_binary | python $TOOL_FOLDERS/searchlibrarysearch_molecularv2_parallelstep.py \
    --parallelism 1 \
    $params.spectra \
    $parallel_params \
    $params.workflow_parameter \
    $params.library \
    intermediateresults \
    convert_binary \
    librarysearch_binary
    """
}



workflow {
    x =Channel.from(1)
    ch=create_parallel_params(x)
    searchlibrarysearch_molecularv2_parallelstep1(ch,params.spectra,params.library)
}
```

I need example how it could be done in nexflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have created a process create_parallel_params whose output is
> parallel_params folder containing {0..9}.json.
>
> I want to pass this create_parallel_params output into another
> process to take these json file in parallel and process it.

There's lots of ways to do this. If the parallel step just needs only a single JSON (and not the whole 'parallel_params' folder), the simplest thing to do might to just be to declare the [multiple output files](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#multiple-output-files) using a [glob](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html#glob) pattern. Then use the [`flatten`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#flatten) operator to emit each file separately. For example:

```
params.spectra = './spectra'
params.library = './library'

params.workflow_parameter = 'foo'
```

```
process create_step {

    output:
    path "parallel_params/*.json"

    """
    mkdir parallel_params
    touch parallel_params/{0..9}.json
    """
}

process parallel_step {
    tag { json_file }

    input:
    path json_file, stageAs: 'parallel_params/*'
    path spectra
    path library

    output:
    path 'intermediate_results'

    """
    mkdir intermediate_results
    echo searchlibrarysearch_molecularv2_parallelstep.py \\
        --parallelism 1 \\
        "${spectra}" \\
        "${json_file}" \\
        "${params.workflow_parameter}" \\
        "${library}" \\
        intermediate_results
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    spectra = file(params.spectra)
    library = file(params.library)

    create_step()

    parallel_step(
        create_step.out.flatten(),
        spectra,
        library,
    )
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.4
Launching `main.nf` [desperate_murdock] DSL2 - revision: e94e1ddf9b
executor >  local (11)
[d3/839bb9] process > create_step                            [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[02/34437b] process > parallel_step (parallel_params/5.json) [100%] 10 of 10 ✔
```

Note also that [third party scripts](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/sharing.html#third-party-scripts) can be granted executable permission and moved into a directory called 'bin' in the root directory of your project repository, i.e. the same directory as your 'main.nf' Nextflow script. Nextflow automatically adds this folder to the `$PATH` environment variable and your scripts will become automatically accessible to each of your pipeline processes. In this case, this lets you call your scripts without having to specify the python intepreter or an absolute path using your `$TOOL_FOLDERS` variable.

Comment: I do not need create json file in script of nextflow. it will be done by parallel_paramgen.py. But i need json file to be passed in searchlibrarysearch_molecularv2_parallelstep1 process. So how to define that path or is there any other way to do?

Comment: Sorry @sudojarvis I don't understand what you mean here. Please correct me if I'm wrong - you're using Nextflow to run a Python script called `parallel_paramgen.py` to create some JSON files under a folder called `parallel_params`. If you name them in your output declaration, you can just flatten them and pass each one through your parallel step. But it's not clear at all what your requirements are exactly. We don't have access to your Python scripts and don't know what they're meant to do. If the above doesn't help, please include a minimal code example that produces the issue.